# negative KL divergence for t-SNE

Tags: python, data-visualization

I am using t-SNE with a dataset of 1262 datapoints of dimension 3288. I have been running t-SNE several times and monitor KL divergence value in order to select the one with the lowest KL value, as Laurens van der Maaten FAQ suggests.

However, I end up having negative KL divergence which I don't understand, as it seems to me that it should be always positive according to Gibbs' inequality.

```
model = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=2, perplexity =30, init='pca', learning_rate=1000)
Projection = model.fit_transform(PartsQTYperCar)

[t-SNE] Computing pairwise distances...
[t-SNE] Computing 91 nearest neighbors...
[t-SNE] Computed conditional probabilities for sample 1000 / 1262
[t-SNE] Computed conditional probabilities for sample 1262 / 1262
[t-SNE] Mean sigma: 0.000000
[t-SNE] Iteration 25: error = 0.0827444, gradient norm = 0.0075889
[t-SNE] Iteration 50: error = 0.0747056, gradient norm = 0.0062666
[t-SNE] Iteration 75: error = 0.0618893, gradient norm = 0.0047267
[t-SNE] Iteration 100: error = 0.0302985, gradient norm = 0.0051550
[t-SNE] Error after 100 iterations with early exaggeration: 0.030298
[t-SNE] Iteration 125: error = -0.0109731, gradient norm = 0.0038695
[t-SNE] Iteration 150: error = -0.0086051, gradient norm = 0.0035785
[t-SNE] Iteration 175: error = -0.0211171, gradient norm = 0.0039716
[t-SNE] Iteration 200: error = 0.0006259, gradient norm = 0.0032799
[t-SNE] Iteration 225: error = -0.0061129, gradient norm = 0.0032859
[t-SNE] Iteration 225: did not make any progress during the last 30 episodes. Finished.
[t-SNE] Error after 225 iterations: -0.006113
```

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43849/how-to-ensure-the-non-negativity-of-kullback-leibler-divergence-kld-metric-rela

Comment: "The K-L divergence is only defined if P and Q both sum to 1 and if Q(i) > 0 for any i such that P(i) > 0." I had several data points that were identical, so I guess this might lead to the fact that the second condition is not true anymore.

Comment: Please remove such identical data points and let us know the outcome.

Comment: KL divergence is always non-negative without duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"The K-L divergence is only defined if P and Q both sum to 1 and if    
Q(i) > 0 for any i such that P(i) > 0."
```

As @*vbvx* pointed out, removing duplicate data points solved the issue.
Although @*vbvx* mentions that the duplicates violate the second condition for KL divergence described above, duplicate values of *i* should only change the frequency of *i* and therefore *P(i)* or *Q(i)* accordingly.

However, if a duplicate is treated as a different item and exists in one of the distributions, *P* or *Q*, the support of *P* will be different from the support of *Q* and the second condition won't hold.